# Batch network tracing?

Tags: geometric-network, arc-hydro

I have a large (3,000+) set of drainage polygons that I derived from the ArcHydro Stormwater Processing workflow. I would like to aggregate them based on the geometric network elements they contribute to. I essentially need to chose a pour point, place a flag, trace upstream, then select polygon features by location (see figure).

Is there a way to automate this process given a pre-determined set of point features (pour points)? I could do it manually, but there are ~500.
[image]

Comment: I assume you are using ArcGIS? Did you try to rebuild your manual process in graphical model builder? See https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/modelbuilder/what-is-modelbuilder.htm

Comment: Thanks MrX. I assumed I might to build it in MB, I was just hoping I had missed an out-of-box solution.

Comment: Not that I know of. But maybe an ArcGIS professional has a good answer for you.